# Is the following convergent or divergent: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+2)/(n^3 + n +5)^{1/2}$?

Tags: calculus

"Is the following convergent or divergent: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+2)/(n^3 + n 
+5)^{1/2}$ ?"

I tried using the Root Test, but got pretty mixed up along the process.

$|(n+2)/(n^3 + n + 5)|^{1/n}$

$=> ln(a) = lim_{n\to\infty} (1/n) * ln((n+2)/(n^3 + n + 5))$

$=> ln((n+2)/(n^3 + n + 5)) / n  => $ indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$?

$=> ((n^3 + n + 5)^{.5} - .5(n+2)(n^3 + n + 5)^{-1.5} * 3n^2 + 1) / 1$ by L'Hopitals

Confusion starts here. Did I do all of that right?

Comment: Is $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant 1} n^{-1/2}$ convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much more direct proof using the comparison test:

- Intuition on why this works:

The numerator looks like $n$, and the denominator looks like $(n^3)^{1/2} = n^{1.5}$. Hence, the overall fraction looks like $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

and the sum is divergent.

- Rigor:

For large $n$, we have $n + 2 > \frac{n}{2}$, and $n^3 + n + 5 \le 2n^3$. Hence,

$$\frac{n + 2}{(n^3 + n + 5)^{1/2}} \geq \frac{n/2}{(2n^3)^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n}}$$

Now invoke the comparison test.

Comment: Oh I see. Comparison test is a lot more applicable than the Root Test in this case then. Just out of curiosity though, was my process for the Root Test correct?

Comment: @Ozera The root test will be [inconclusive](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+((x+%2B+2\)+%2F+sqrt(x%5E3+%2B+x+%2B+5\)\)%5E(1%2Fx\)+as+x+tends+to+infinity) in this case. As far as the application of L'Hospital's rule, be more careful with your parentheses - it looks like you applied the quotient rule but only included the denominator in one of the terms.

Comment: I actually attempted the product rule. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Besides to another approaches, you could use the following tests:

> Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}~n^pu_n=A$. Then:
>
> - If $p>1$ and $A$ is finite then $\sum u_n$ converges.
> - If $p\le1$ and $A\neq0$ or $A=\infty$ then $\sum u_n$ diverges.

Now take $p=1/2$.

Comment: $+_+^++ \ddot\smile$

Comment: Getting better! Thanks...A bit more time at the clinic this week, and perhaps half-days next week, then I think I'll just have a few outpatient appointments here and there.

Comment: @amWhy: I inly wish to see you here as we met weeks ago. [Kroger](http://www.kroger.com/Pages/default.aspx) has great supplements for men and foe women. Are you allowed to take these kinds of pills?

Comment: Hello, dear friend! I hope you are well? ;-)